# BrowserMob. How to configure BrowserMobProxy through httpclient

Tags: java, browsermob, browsermob-proxy

I am trying to use BrowserMob proxy library (net.lightbody.bmp) to intercept http requests from some default website (for instance: "https://default.com") and my question is how to do that ?

```
BrowserMobProxy proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
proxy.start(9091, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), InetAddress.getByName("default.com"));
```

and after that I create anonymous class for filtering request

```
 proxy.addRequestFilter(new RequestFilter() {
      @Override
      public HttpResponse filterRequest(HttpRequest request, HttpMessageContents contents, HttpMessageInfo messageInfo) {}...
```

but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //start the proxy
    BrowserMobProxy bmproxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
    bmproxy.start(); // specify the port and address here.

    Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(bmproxy);

    // configure it as a desired capability
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();        

    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy)

    // start the browser up
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

    // enable more detailed HAR capture, if desired (see CaptureType for the complete list)
    bmproxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT, CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT);

    // create a new HAR with the label "ebay.de"
    bmproxy.newHar("ebay.de");

    // open ebay.de
    driver.get("http://ebay.de");

    // get the HAR data
    Har har = bmproxy.getHar();
    File harFile = new File("<filename>.har" );
    har.writeTo(harFile);

    driver.quit();
```

Hope it helps.